# Exception with auth

Tags: spring, spring-security, jwt

I have config

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

private final JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;

private static final String ADMIN_ENDPOINT = "/api/v1/admin/**";
private static final String LOGIN_ENDPOINT = "/api/v1/auth/login";

@Autowired
public SecurityConfig(JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider) {
    this.jwtTokenProvider = jwtTokenProvider;
}

@Bean(name = BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
@Override
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .httpBasic().disable()
            .csrf().disable()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(LOGIN_ENDPOINT).permitAll()
            .antMatchers(ADMIN_ENDPOINT).hasRole("ADMIN")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .apply(new JwtConfigurer(jwtTokenProvider));
}
```

}

And rest controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/v1/auth/")
public class AuthenticationRestControllerV1 {
private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
private final JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;
private final UserService userService;

@Autowired
public AuthenticationRestControllerV1(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager, JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider, UserService userService) {
    this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    this.jwtTokenProvider = jwtTokenProvider;
    this.userService = userService;
}

@PostMapping("login")
public ResponseEntity login(@RequestBody AuthenticationRequestDto requestDto) {
    try {
        String username = requestDto.getUsername();
        authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, requestDto.getPassword()));
        User user = userService.findByUsername(username);

        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User with username: " + username + " not found");
        }

        String token = jwtTokenProvider.createToken(username, user.getRoles());

        Map<Object, Object> response = new HashMap<>();
        response.put("username", username);
        response.put("token", token);

        return ResponseEntity.ok(response);
    } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
        throw new BadCredentialsException("Invalid username or password");
    }
}
}
```

If I send POST query through POSTMAN, there are error

> java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
>       at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:205) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
>       at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:195) ~[spring-security-core-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$AuthenticationManagerDelegator.authenticate(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:501) ~[spring-security-config-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
>       at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor52.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
>       at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]

Problem is situated in controller, in this line:

```
authenticationManager.authenticate(new 
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username,requestDto.getPassword()));
```

How to fix this problem?

Comment: Having same issue. I get a JdkDynamicAopProxy instead of authenticationManager auto wired Bean